# Google Spreadsheet - Convert total hours in duration format

Tags: excel, google-sheets

How do I convert a number of hours in duration?

Example: in cell A1 I have **176**.

I want cell A2 to have **176:00:00**

I want to transform the number 176 in 176 hours (duration). Is that possible? Because if I type 176 in a cell and format as duration, it converts to 4224:00:00 for some reasion ... thanks!

Comment: You need to divide it by 24. `=A1/24` then format it properly.  The reason is that hours are a decimal based on 24 hour being 1.

Comment: Thanks! It worked ... please reply it as an answer so I can set your reply as the correct one, I can't set this comment here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is how time is viewed.  Dates are integers while time is a decimal based on a 24 hour period being 1.

To convert a number to time one must divide it by 24.  In A2:

```
=A1/24
```

Will give a decimal value that then can be formatted as time that will give the correct number of hours.